# In typescript, wierd inference from exact type from union type. How to handle it?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I want to define axios response with one union type ( when success /error )
and handle and inference date type by status code with user defined type guard.

IntRange is a just union type from n to m int. ( n | n+1 | n+2 | ... | m)

```
type SuccessCode = IntRange<200, 300>
type ErrorCode = IntRange<0, 200> | IntRange<300, 600>

interface SuccessResponse<T> extends Omit<AxiosResponse<T>, 'status'> {
   status: SuccessCode
}

interface ErrorResponse extends Omit<AxiosResponse<{message: string}, 'status'> {
   status: ErrorCode
}

type ResType<T> = SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse

function isSuccessStatus(status: number): status is SuccessCode {
  return Number.isInteger(status) && (status >= 200 && status < 300)
}
```

And I expect to when isSuccess(status) -> data type will be inferenced by T.

But in my code,

```
if (status === 204)
```

data type is inferenced by T correctly,

but

```
if (isSuccessStatus(status))
```

it consoles true, but data type is inference by `T | {message: string}` not T.

what is wrong with my code ? please help me ..

Just enumerating status === 200 || status === 201 || .... is working.

And after isSuccessStatus (user-defined type guards) => status type is inferenced by SuccessCode.

but data (must be T) is just T | {message: string} .
I don't know why this wierd thing happens ..

Comment: It seems like `isSuccess` function is missing and it's not clear how you are using `ResType<T>` type

Comment: @NirG Could you explain more? 'is SuccessCode' is for user defined type guard

Comment: How are we supposed to help if we don't have access to the definitions of `IntRange`? Please include all relevant code and a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q).

Comment: @vera I think it was enough to specify as example. I am sorry for that. IntRange is `type Enumerate<N extends number, Acc extends number[] = []> = Acc['length'] extends N
  ? Acc[number]
  : Enumerate<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>`

`type IntRange<F extends number, T extends number> = Exclude<Enumerate<T>, Enumerate<F>>` 
So, IntRange<200, 300> : 200 | 201 | 202 .. | 299

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a self-contained [mre], with all definitions required (comments are not sufficient unfortunately).  The goal is that others can take your code example and paste it into a standalone IDE (no axios dependency, for example) to see the problem you're seeing.  If they can't do that easily then it's harder for them to help.

Comment: You would have to make your type guard narrow the entire response object like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5OnBW) for it to work.